# TypeScript discriminated union

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I have the interfaces

```
interface Teacher {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    category: string;
    age: number;
    workExperience: number;
    isLikeCoffe: boolean;
}

interface CodingTeacher extends Teacher {
    category: 'coding';
    programmingLanguage: string;
}

interface MusicTeacher extends Teacher {
    category: 'music';
    instrument: string;
}
```

I have User-Defined Type Guards

```
const isMusicTeacher = (teacher: Teacher): teacher is MusicTeacher => {
    return teacher.category === "music";
}

const isCodingTeacher = (teacher: Teacher): teacher is CodingTeacher => {
    return teacher.category === "coding";
}
```

When i want to get all the music teachers i can do it like this

```
getMusicTeachers(): Array<MusicTeacher> {
  return this.getTeachers().filter(isMusicTeacher);
}
```

But I also need to get a lot, where only those who meet certain given criteria, and then difficulties arise.
Since I only need to get music teachers who are "professional"
And i do it like this

```
teachers: Teacher[] = [];
type TeacherCategory = "coding" | "music";

getTeachers<T extends Teacher>(category?: TeacherCategory): Array<T> {

  const activeTeachers = this.teachers.filter(t => t.workExperience > 20 && t.isLikeCoffe);

  if (!category) {
    return activeTeachers as T[];
  }

  return activeTeachers.filter(t => t.category === category) as T[];
}
```

or i need to get one

```
public findTeacherById<T extends Teacher>(id: number, category?: TeacherCategory): T {

  return this.teachers.find(t => (!category || t.category == category) && t.id == id);
}
```

Am I doing the correct description of the return types?
In this case, when I want to get only those models knowing their category

```
const teacher: CodingTeacher = this.myService.findTeacherById(1, 'coding');

const teachers: MusicTeacher = this.myService.getTeachers('music');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoUQC2sg3gWAChkTlgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG4jSa56JqBnMKKADmbYqQRxIQgPZQAnnwHDRHOEJ40GzKCtIB3WQGsAogA8ADtGAQQSanSat2pYLwAywQxADC0mDA1GaWkAGwwQUQBfIiJQSFhEFF9yYXQsHAhTSBByXjQMBGwoPGcSCSlZBWQAcgRpFJAhat0ScyhpISguemE3OEbaNQ1%20QUaomMI46HgkZABZWl5gBDTCjKybXPz04oIxMskIGXlqavpF5ebSshARhhswRVGRImjCIjrbsDJeBaWVgpFZAAXmQAApIDtqKsigBKaiQtbFVzzC4AnYggB8JX2yCgEDAtCgIGQiKKADpykdKiDgaCAETnf708bvQiffg-ZKpQE4UEQ3lQaGC%20GkwU-ZDcxowvnYvYcfGE4linaUw7HOS0hl1BpCFmvCZgOSWbZI7zqmna%20rCenIAA%20yEZaP1bIQITgvDyczk3ndnpxHHUYBlUF4YNFAEEoF05AAeENy64KglEkkAbQAui1kG9rkG-ssQ2HI9G4HGC%20ikYnccmlSSwJhXOSg0Xw%20SYMAQvEwa4KyHYdnc7igwAFdoBT3AaQgOAhIvx5CZbJbBNgqkagD8wp25oq8hLMfj1aT4mnnMQYGAADcIEWQaTG7xmwTW7D253u99gdiwOSDFATAsKwbFmbEACYAAZkAAMmg0lyVcDwvF8fwIAHCYOA4YAYHBABCddKlhANMJIxVU2QC9r1vQU8g9NBM2zDghxIkgyOVSibyLd8u2gCEsXggj5C1ZBBLkIi6NQBjriHa5zFoRgQmWZAOxyEMACE5AASXIBcl02PJVwoewtGgAAaESLXkLdTSKXdqX3aEcRPViU2VBsmxbGi2xU8g%20O-PDRPtB1f0CukLL3MSYLg38KFpMhyHEgzBwNV0z2%20MloGoKUhBDe8QAgPR5h9P1i3fVTBQ07TY2y1cAEZzNqa1GmqdD2TSlUkV4ag%200FTM8oKorfQ9UrR3HCBJ2nWdWzONEWpYIA)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't have to declare like that:

```
const teacher = new MyClass().findTeacherById<CodingTeacher>(1, 'coding');
// or
const teacher: CodingTeacher = this.myService.findTeacherById(1, 'coding');
```

Using [Intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) can help you get the type you want without declaring type or passing generics.

**The following is core idea:**

```
type TFn1 = (a: number) => number;
type TFn2 = (a: string) => string;
// be careful of this any here
const Fn: TFn1 & TFn2 = (a: number | string): any => {
  return a;
};

Fn(1); // type is (a: number) => number
Fn('2'); // type is (a: string) => string
Fn(true); // error
```

Then let's take `findTeacherById` as an example, it can be:

```
type T1 = (id: number, category: 'coding') => CodingTeacher;
type T2 = (id: number, category: 'music') => MusicTeacher;

...

public findTeacherById: T1 & T2 = (id: number, category: TeacherCategory): any => {
  return this.getTeachers().find((t) => (!category || t.category === category) && t.id === id);
}
...

const teacher1 = new MyClass().findTeacherById(1, 'coding'); // type returned is CodingTeacher
const teacher2 = new MyClass().findTeacherById(2, 'music'); // type returned is MusicTeacher
const teacher3 = new MyClass().findTeacherById(3, 'test'); // 'test' is not assignable
};
```

To unify `T1` and `T2` for convenience, we can declare one uniform type:

```
type TU<T> = (id: number, category: T extends { category: string } ? T['category'] : never) => T;

type TFindTeacherById = TU<CodingTeacher> & TU<MusicTeacher>;
```